# How to wait for the updated value in an activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I have an activity that displays a number. The number is obtained from `SharedPreferences` e.g

```
int num=pref.getInt(myAsyncTask.MYNUMBER,0);
```

The `SharedPreference` is loaded inside an `AsyncTask` where calculations take place (that involve retrieving data from `db` and so on). So, `OnCreate()` of the activity I run the `Asynctask` to calculate the value. However, the value is not always updated to the latest one when I launch the activity. This might be because `Asynctask` takes more time to calculate the new value than the the action of displaying the value inside the activity. How can I delay the execution of the method displaying the value until the `Asynctask` finishes with the process of the new one?

**[[EDIT]]**
I removed sharedpreferences. I use the `onPostExecute()` method to get the result. However, the behaviour is similar. The result is returned after the value is displayed so i couldn't see anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the calculation doesn't take more than few second, the simplest solution is to use [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29), this method will block UI thread execution and make UI thread waiting for AsyncTask to finish:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ... ...
  MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = nee MyAsyncTask();
  myAsyncTask.execute();
  myAsyncTask.get(); // alternatively you can use AsyncTask.(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
  ... ...
}
```

Bear in mind that it blocks UI thrread execution, if your calculation is longer than 5 seconds, you will probably get ANR exception.

Since you already use AsyncTask, a more reasonable solution is moving execution of the method displaying the value into AsyncTask.onPostExecute(), this is the exactly reason why AsyncTask exist in API to solve this kind if scenario.

Comment: @JustCurious, I still prefer move view update code into onPostExecute(), which is sufficient in most cases.

Comment: nice answer..but it does not work... i still dont get the value. it is however freezes for a second. I will some more of my code maybe it will help

Comment: @JustCurious, onPostExecute() method requires a parameter Result which is return from doInBackground, make sure you have implemented your AsyncTask properly, check out the [usage section](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in the API

Answer (score 0):

Just use `listener` concept, or just 'pass' your Activity to your asynctask so It can call the main thread.

Comment: Using a listener would be better, to prevent your activity/AsyncTask from being tightly-coupled

Answer (score 0):

If the value is not showing as correct at the time you launch the activity you should set the visibility of the View to View.GONE so it doesn't appear, then change the visibility back to visible when you have the result. To update the value you could implement a listener on your activity that gets called by the AsyncTask.

If its going to take a significant time (more than a few seconds) you might want to also use a progress dialog so the user understands that they need to wait.

Comment: I will use a progress bar. The time is not more than few seconds though. The problem is that I want the value to be displayed when the activity is launched for the very first time so i want to somehow wait for the asynctask to finish